# why is the line #!/bin/ksh is the first line in a shell script

Tags: unix, shell

`#!/bin/ksh` is the first line in a shell script always

what is the importance of this line and why is it kept as the first line.

Comment: This is documented in the `execve(2)` man page.

Comment: Try searching on this site for "shebang".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line tells the operating system what interpreter to invoke to run the script.

Without it, there's no way to know that this script needs to be run using the `ksh` interpreter.

The sequence is known as a "shebang", and you can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 2):

If the file is executable, it tells the os, which program can execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

it signals that the script is to be executed by ksh (instead of any of the other shells)